# How to group time column into 5 second intervals and count rows using Presto?

Tags: sql, apache-zeppelin, presto

I am using Presto and Zeppelin. There are a lot of raw datas.
I have to summarize those datas.

I wanna group time every 5 seconds.

```
serviceType        logType     date
------------------------------------------------------
service1           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:23.206
service1           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:23.207
service1           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:25.206
service2           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:24.206
service1           log2        2017-10-24 23:00:27.206
service1           log2        2017-10-24 23:00:29.302
```

then the result

```
serviceType        logType     date                       cnt
--------------------------------------------------------------
service1           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:20          2
service2           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:20          1
service1           log1        2017-10-24 23:00:25          1
service1           log2        2017-10-24 23:00:25          2
```

first, I have to migrate stored datas to new tables.

second, I have to group datas and save to the new table realtime.

It's hard to write sql script.

Please help me.

Do I have to use python interpreter?

Answer (score 10):

You can

1. discard millisecond part of a `timestamp` with `date_trunc`
2. you can round a `timestamp` without millisecond part to 5 seconds with `ts - interval '1' second * (second(ts) % 5)`

Example putting this together:

```
presto> SELECT ts_rounded, count(*)
     -> FROM (
     ->     SELECT date_trunc('second', ts) - interval '1' second * (second(ts) % 5) AS ts_rounded
     ->     FROM (VALUES timestamp '2017-10-24 23:01:20.206',
     ->         timestamp '2017-10-24 23:01:23.206',
     ->         timestamp '2017-10-24 23:01:23.207',
     ->         timestamp '2017-10-24 23:01:26.206') AS t(ts)
     -> )
     -> GROUP BY ts_rounded ORDER BY ts_rounded;
       ts_rounded        | _col1
-------------------------+-------
 2017-10-24 23:01:20.000 |     3
 2017-10-24 23:01:25.000 |     1
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

this gives 5 minute buckets

```
from_unixtime((cast(to_unixtime(timestamp_column_name) as bigint)/60/5)*60*5)
```

this gives 60 seconds buckets

```
from_unixtime((cast(to_unixtime(timestamp_column_name) as bigint)/60)*60)
```

this gives 5 seconds buckets

```
from_unixtime((cast(to_unixtime(timestamp_column_name) as bigint)/5)*5)
```

This is by date the best trick I know, since it's super simple and works on all databases. It uses the loss of precision when dividing for the rounding. We have all timestamps in UTC milliseconds, so aggregations by windows is quite easy.