# How to test for 5 minute intervals with SQL, given Windows Event Manager event timestamps in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, windows, amazon-athena, presto

I am using Athena in AWS with Windows Event Manager logs to construct some queries for security events. One of those is that I want to query for machines reporting 3 or more failed login attempts in under 5 minutes.

The timestamp column is formatted as such: `2019-03-25T19:18:10.7954381Z`

I have already completed finding machines with that specific event id: `SELECT machinename,
         COUNT(eventid)
FROM windows
WHERE eventid = 4625
GROUP BY  machinename
HAVING COUNT(eventid = 4625) >= 3;`

It simply returns all machines with that eventid greater than or equal to 3, for any timestamp.

My problem is this: how would I go about implementing logic in SQL to check if that specific eventid has occurred within a 5 minute time span with that kind of time stamp, rather than just displaying all times?

This is my first foray into SQL; any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
Theo had solution. Posting here:

`SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    FLOOR(
      TO_UNIXTIME(
        DATE_PARSE(substr(timecreated, 1, 16), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i')
      )/300
    ) * 300
  ) AS five_minute_window,
  machine-name,
  COUNT(event-id) AS event_count
FROM table
WHERE event-id = 4625
GROUP BY 1, machine-name
HAVING COUNT(event-id = 4625) >= 3;`

I had to shave off the fractional seconds as there were some anomalous time stamps which were not formatted as such (only whole seconds).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group time column into 5 second intervals and count rows using Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066024/how-to-group-time-column-into-5-second-intervals-and-count-rows-using-presto)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Athena you can use the `DATE_TRUNC` function to truncate a timestamp to whole minutes, hours, etc. Unfortunately it does not support multiples of units, so five minutes is not possible.

I usually do it like this: `FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(TO_UNIXTIME("timestamp")/300) * 300)`. What it does it that it converts to a UNIX timestamp, i.e. number of seconds since 1970, divide by 300 to get the number of five minute intervals since 1970, round it down to an integer, and multiply with 300 again to convert back to seconds, and then convert back to a timestamp. This works for any interval, just change 300 to 1800 to round to half hours, etc.

Your timestamp format is not supported natively by Athena so you will need to parse it, that is done with [`DATE_PARSE`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) – for example `DATE_PARSE("timestamp_column", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`.

A full example might look something like this:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    FLOOR(
      TO_UNIXTIME(
        DATE_PARSE("timestamp_column", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
      )/300
    ) * 300
  ) AS five_minute_window,
  COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM some_table
GROUP BY 1
```

That would give you the number of rows in each five minute window. You can add a `WHERE` to filter on specific rows, and outer queries to find the windows with many events, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to round a time at n minutes right?  I am putting below oracle syntax but note that all databases have similar functioins.  Approach is to "round" or "truncate" the data at that minute.  So it is 10:43 - return 10:40.  Once you get that you can group by that

- sysdate in oracle returns current date/time - for testing
- to_char converts a date or number given format
- trunc (or round) are used to truncate numeric operation
- to_date is to convert a string in a format to a date

```
select actual_date,
       to_date(to_char(actual_date,'YYYYMMDDHH24') || min_trunc_5,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') rouded_to_5_dt,
       min_trunc_5
from
(
    select sysdate  actual_date, 
           ltrim(to_char(trunc(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'MI')/5))*5,'09')) min_trunc_5
    from dual
) x
```

it returned for me

```
actual_date      rounded_to_5_dt min_trunc_5
20190410084837   20190410084500  45
```

See how 48 became 45.  Now if do this type of operation on any date and group by that I will be grouping all data in that 5 minute range

Comment: Is `dual` and `sysdate` available in Athena (Presto)?

Comment: dual is most likely not needed.  That is a single row single column dummy table in oracle so that you can always do a from clause.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html has information that you need about SQL functions in athena